# New NestJS project without prettier

Tags: nestjs

when I create a new NestJS project via the CLI, it automatically adds prettier to the project. I don't like to use prettier. How can I create new NestJS projects without prettier? I don't even have prettier installed on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

`prettier` is installed as a `devDependency` to the application. There's no option to not install it, at least via the Nest CLI. With that said, you do have a few options

1. create your own schematic or GitHub template that would allow you to bypass Nest's standard install (you'd have to clone it each time, but that's at least an option)
2. use the `--skip-install` flag and run the installation yourself after removing the `prettier` dependency and `prettierrc` file
3. create a shell script that runs `nest new` and takes care of removing prettier for you.

Comment: so, I just userd the command npm uninstall prettier and npm uninstall --save prettier and same for eslint-config-prettier. so now I can use this project as template on github?